# Complex locus of circle

Tags: complex-numbers

In my book it is given

$\left\lvert \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right\rvert = k$ where k is not equal to 1 &0.

Here z represents the locus of circle .

But I could not understand here what is $z_1$ & $z_2$

Comment: @MyGlasses circle

Comment: Maybe worth noting that, geometrically, the locus of points $z$ with constant ratio between distances to two fixed points $z_1,z_2$ is a [circle of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_circles#Definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols $z_1$ and $z_2$ represent fixed numbers in the complex plane. The formula 
$$\left\lvert \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right\rvert = k$$
states that the distance between $z$ and $z_1$ is a constant multiple of the distance between $z$ and $z_2$ and your book asserts that the set of all $z$ satisfying this is a circle.

Here's one way to understand this. If
$$\left\lvert \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right\rvert = k,$$
then
$$\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2} = k \, e^{it}$$
for some $t$. If we solve this for $z$, we obtain
$$z = \frac{k \, e^{i t} z_2-z_1}{k \, e^{i t} - 1}.$$
Thus, $z$ is the image of a point on the unit circle under the Mobius transformation
$$w \to \frac{k \, w \, z_2-z_1}{k \, w - 1}$$
and Mobius transformations are well known to map circles to circles or lines. In the case that $k=1$, we have that $1\to\infty$ and the image of the unit circle is a line. In fact, when $k=1$, we should get the line that bisects the line segment from $z_1$ to $z_2$.

Here's an illustration of the situation when $z_1=1+i$, $z_2=-2-i$, and $k=1/2$:

[image]

If we draw a line segment from $1+i$ to a point on the circle that segment should be half as long as a segment from the point $-2-i$ to the same point on the circle.

Comment: So z1 and z2 can be any points

Comment: @koolman Well, they should be distinct.